# Create a join out of two belongs_to relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a way that I can have an AR relationship that encapsulates two `belongs_to` relationships that point to the same model?

```
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'Account'
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'Account'
end
```

In essence, I want to be able to run queries that rely on nested joins like so with `accounts` referring to either the foreign key `sender_id` or `recipient_id` pointing to the `events` table:

```
Transaction.joins(accounts: :banks)...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Transaction.includes(sender: :banks, recipient: :banks).where(banks: {name: 'My Bank'})
```

*Tested working with a replicated schema of yours assuming I understood your question correctly*